# Check all option on Aurelia, can this be improved

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Right now we have the following code which fills kind of "dirty"
with the power of aurelia bindings:

**HTML**

```
<input class="order-input-root" type="checkbox" click.delegate="checkAll()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
    checkAll(){

    if($("input:checkbox.order-input-root").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("input:checkbox.order-input").removeAttr("checked");
        $("input:checkbox.order-input").click();
        return true;
    }else
    {
        $("input:checkbox.order-input").removeAttr("checked");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to improve this, is there any built-in functionality on aurelia?, my concern is that if I want to have different lists on a single page this code is going to be a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all checkboxes are properly bound, you could easily achieve this by using the `change` event.

**JS:**

```
export class Welcome {
  constructor() {
    this.isAllChecked = false;
    this.items = [
      { display: 'test 1', checked: false },
      { display: 'test 2', checked: false },
      { display: 'test 3', checked: false },
      { display: 'test 4', checked: false },
    ];
  }

  checkAll() {
    this.items.forEach(i => i.checked = this.isAllChecked);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked.bind="isAllChecked" change.delegate="checkAll()" />
    Check All
  </label>
  <label repeat.for="item of items" style="display: block">
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked.bind="item.checked" />
    ${item.display}
  </label>
</template>
```

**Here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/AzU1dtOVgRpkVUHvupcZ?p=preview**

If for some reason the `change` method is not enough, you could use the `bindingEngine` to observe the checkbox. Like this:

**JS:**

```
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding'; //or aurelia-framework
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection'; //or aurelia-framework

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class Welcome {
  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
    this.checkAll = false;
    this.items = [
      { display: 'test 1', checked: false },
      { display: 'test 2', checked: false },
      { display: 'test 3', checked: false },
      { display: 'test 4', checked: false },
    ];
    this.checkAllSubscriber = this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this, 'checkAll')
      .subscribe((newValue, oldValue) => {
        this.items.forEach(i => i.checked = newValue);
      });
  }

  detached() {
    this.checkAllSubscriber.dispose();
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked.bind="checkAll" />
    Check All
  </label>
  <label repeat.for="item of items" style="display: block">
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked.bind="item.checked" />
    ${item.display}
  </label>
</template>
```

**Remember to call `dispose()` when you no longer need it.**

**Here is a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/uWjIEN8ep184af3w5Ay9?p=preview**

These are the solutions I have found. I will update this answer if I find another approach.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fabio I went for this solution, but tried with yours as well, what do you think:

$("input:checkbox.order-input").prop('checked',$("input:checkbox.order-input-root").prop('checked'));

Comment: It seems like a good solution but not related to Aurelia bindings. It is related to jQuery. Anyway, choose the one that makes you feel more comfortable :)

Comment: I will change it to aurelia for sure, but I need to talk with the other programmer that is using jquery every where :D that's why I marked your answer