# Aurelia: How to bind to an open() method

Tags: aurelia

In the code below I am trying to show (open is the method used to show it) a toast in Polymer.

I have a variable in my viewmodel called 'toastHelp_visible' that is either false (at startup) or set to true by a button click.

```
<paper-toast id="toastHelp" duration="0" text="This toast will stay opened until you close it, or open another toast.">
    <paper-button click.delegate="toast1.toggle()" open.bind="toastHelp_visible" class="yellow-button">Close now!</paper-button>
</paper-toast>
```

The Polymer method is : toast1.open()

I never see the toast and there are no errors in the console.

Any tips appreciated.

Bob

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking for... but you could attach some handler to detect changes in the "open" variable. If open is true, you call the method. This thread might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366297/check-all-option-on-aurelia-can-this-be-improved/36368632#36368632

Answer (score 1):

I should have looked more carefully. I have attached the bind to the button not the toast.

I should have bound to opened not open too.